# What has been gained by downvoting a question and deleting the accepted answer?

Tags: discussion

This [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/60572/what-is-the-connection-between-the-ten-commandments-and-the-two-commandments-of) appeared 22 hours ago and I answered it within an hour. Although the question was badly worded, through genuine ignorance, there was no doubt what was being sought.

The OP upvoted my answer and accepted it within another hour or few.

I therefore fail to understand what has subsequently been gained  :-

- by downvoting the Question
- by three people telling the OP (new to the site) that the question was not clear
- by making many comments to my answer
- and, lastly, by deleting my answer (which the OP had already accepted)

I ask again - what has been gained ?

Comment: Your answer isn't deleted.

Comment: @curiousdannii It's been downvoted -3 and it appears semi-darkened on my screen. I understood that to be a delete.

Comment: A deleted post appears with a reddish shade, and is only visible to the author, mods, and +10k rep users. The grey shade is auto applied to all answers with a score under -2.

Comment: @fredsbend Ah ! Thank you. I didn't know that. Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect in this case your answer is attracting extra down votes precisely because it was marked as accepted by the OP. An answer that is deemed wrong might normally attract a couple of down votes if it has no up votes, but because it has been marked accepted, some people may be wanting to counteract the authority such acceptance gives to it. You also see the same thing with highly upvoted but contentious answers: lots of answers have net scores of -2 or -3, whether that's +0 and -3 or +30 and -33.

Now is there any legitimacy for the community to declare an answer "wrong" even though the question asker accepted it? Actually the way the Stack Exchange system is set up, that's always a possibility. Good answers are seen to be good by the community as a whole endorsing them through their votes. In this specific case, the OP doesn't appear to be very knowledgeable, asking not just about the relationship between the 10 commandments and the 2 commandments, but also what are the 2 commandments. A large number of people in the community disagree with you both about what the 2 commandments are, and about the relationship between the 10 and the 2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it. I have only been here a month and I am still learning how Stack Exchange works. Regards.

Answer (score 4):

Answering off topic or poorly worded questions will frequently earn down votes. If you aren't sure how the question will be received, you should wait to answer. The comments on the question indicate the issue, which is mostly confusion. Many of us believe the question is unclear. You answered so quickly that you wouldn't have seen these comments. Great job jumping on that, and helping quickly. Hang in there and you'll soon be able to ride the SE wave with the best of them.

Comment: Yes, I am beginning to see the wisdom of waiting for questions to be well received before diving in. Thank you for that.